# Analyze and edit links in html code with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a part of html page.  I have to find all out links from it and replace them with the mark `<can_be_link>`.

Next code do almost all what I want, but it fails on links that are located on some lines (not on one) and that lines starts with tabs (in my example this is link with http://bad.com).

How to solve this issue correctly?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import BeautifulSoup
import re

if __name__=="__main__":
    body = """                  
    <a href="http://good.com" target="_blank">good link</a>
    <ul>
                        <li class="FOLLOW">
                            <a href="http://bad.com" target="_blank">
                                <em></em>
                                <span>
                                    <strong class="FOLLOW-text">Follow On</strong>
                                    <strong class="FOLLOW-logo"></strong>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
    </ul>

"""
    metka_link = '<can_be_link>'
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(body)
    hrefs = soup.findAll(name = 'a', attrs = { 'href': re.compile('\.*') })
    repl = {}
    for t in hrefs:
        line = str(t)
            # print '\n'*2, line
        if not t.has_key('href'):
            continue
        href = t['href'].lower()
        if href.find('http') == 0 or href.find('//') == 0:
            body = body.replace(line, metka_link)

    print body
```

The rezult is

```
<can_be_link>
<ul>
                                        <li class="FOLLOW">
                                                <a href="http://bad.com" target="_blank">
                                                        <em></em>
                                                        <span>
                                                                <strong class="FOLLOW-text">Follow On</strong>
                                                                <strong class="FOLLOW-logo"></strong>
                                                        </span>
                                                </a>
                                        </li>
</ul>
```

But the desired result must be

```
<can_be_link>
<ul>
                                        <li class="FOLLOW">
                                                <can_be_link>
                                        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is your desired result in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [replace_with()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) method:

> PageElement.replace_with() removes a tag or string from the tree, and
>   replaces it with the tag or string of your choice

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

body = """
<a href="http://good.com" target="_blank">good link</a>
<ul>
                    <li class="FOLLOW">
                        <a href="http://bad.com" target="_blank">
                            <em></em>
                            <span>
                                <strong class="FOLLOW-text">Follow On</strong>
                                <strong class="FOLLOW-logo"></strong>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
</ul>

"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')

links = soup.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    link = link.replace_with('<can_be_link>')

print soup.prettify(formatter=None)
```

prints:

```
<can_be_link>
<ul>
 <li class="FOLLOW">
  <can_be_link>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Note the import statement - use the 4th `BeautifulSoup` version since `Beautiful Soup 3 is no longer being developed, and that Beautiful Soup 4 is recommended for all new projects.`

Comment: Thanks, I used the 4th BeautifulSoup.

But I have next problems with your code


* On real pages I get sometimes next error with `soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')` - `HTMLParser.HTMLParseError: malformed start tag, at line 1540, column 30`


* I should get all another code of page unchangable, but this `soup.prettify(formatter=None)` change indents in formating.

Comment: I have solved this error `HTMLParser.HTMLParseError: malformed start tag, at line 1540, column 30` with `soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html5lib')`. But I still need all other code to remain unchanged (without new indents).

Comment: I do not know how correct is it, but this code do what I want: `body = soup |     body = body.encode('utf8')`